# Setting cookie in javascript and get in ashx handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, ashx

I am setting cookie in `javascript` as below

```
document.cookie = "xyz=CookieValue;";
```

after that handler is getting called and I am trying to get that value using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["xyz"];
```

but it comes `null`.

Why so?

Comment: you can try like this HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies

Comment: Can you post a little more code? I created simple handler and all works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Path` of the Cookie to `/` when creating it.

```
document.cookie="xyz=CookieValue;path=/";
```

Like that, the cookie is valid on the whole domain and not only on the page which created it.